# Get Facebook Friends list and display it in custom view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, facebook-sdk-3.0, facebook-friends

I'm trying to get FaceBook Friend list , and display it in custom view like "foresqure App"

what I mean "foursquare" ask for the permission and to post on your wall inside the app without leaving the app to the browser or to the app Facebook ?  after that the app get all friends and display it in custom tableView.

[image]

here what I tried :

```
if (!FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
    // if the session is closed, then we open it here, and establish a handler for state changes
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile", @"user_friends"]
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                      FBSessionState state,
                                                      NSError *error) {
                                      if (error) {
                                          UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                                              message:error.localizedDescription
                                                                                             delegate:nil
                                                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];
                                          [alertView show];
                                      } else if (session.isOpen) {
                                          //[self pickFriendsButtonClick:sender];
                                          NSLog(@"aaaa");
                                          FBRequest* friendsRequest = [FBRequest requestForMyFriends];
                                          [friendsRequest startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                                                        NSDictionary* result,
                                                                                        NSError *error) {
                                              NSArray* friends = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
                                              NSLog(@"Found: %i friends", friends.count);
                                              for (NSDictionary<FBGraphUser>* friend in friends) {
                                                  NSLog(@"I have a friend named %@ with id %@", friend.name, friend.id);
                                              }
                                          }];
                                      }
                                  }];

}
```

In this case it will open the safari to ask for permision not inside the app and friend array allows nill or count = 0.

Comment: @DarshanKunjadiya check this http://www.filedropper.com/testface

Comment: in my mac this code is work perfectly . i am change only my facebook app id and get all friend list .

Comment: I had this bug when I forgot to check Native iOS App (in Facebook Developers Page) and typed-in my Bundle ID, which is same as Bundle identifier in your Xcode project. (including your project name at the end.) I also had the setting in Facebook Developers Page which enabled SandBox mode. I disabled Sandbox mode too to get this work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code ..

Firstly call this method like this ..

```
[self FBFriendList];
```

And add this two methods.

```
-(void)FBFriendList
{
if (!FBSession.activeSession.isOpen)
{
    // if the session is closed, then we open it here, and establish a handler for state changes

    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,FBSessionState state, NSError *error)
     {
         if (error)
         {
             UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:error.localizedDescription delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
             [alertView show];
             [alertView release];
         }
         else if(session.isOpen)
         {
             [self FBFriendList];
             [self fb_frnd_use_this_app];
         }
     }];

    return;
}
}

-(void)fb_frnd_use_this_app
   {
    FBRequest *request =  [FBRequest  requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends"
                                                parameters:@{@"fields":@"name,installed,first_name,picture"}
                                                HTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error)
     {


         NSLog(@"%@",result);
         int count = 0;
         NSMutableArray *frnd_arr = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
         for (int i = 0; i < [frnd_arr count]; i++)
         {
             NSLog(@"%@",frnd_arr);
             count++;
         }

         NSLog(@"%@",app.Arr_Facebook_Frnd);
         app.fbfriendCount =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",count];

     }];
}
```

Hope this code is useful for you.

Comment: the same result open :open safari to ask for permission which is not what I want :(

Comment: @Omarj permission is mandatory for get friendlist of facebook.

Comment: I know that, what i'm trying to is git the permission like Foursqure app look at the photo I attached ?

Comment: @Omarj what i am not get it ??

Comment: Firs of all , the code inside openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions block never get called ? even NSLog.//

Comment: did u see the photo up there ? when u download foursquare app and try to checkIn/out and click on Facebook icon it ask you to access your Facebook account and get some info and ask for permission in alert view and it never goes out the app ?

Comment: @Omarj means you will try to get friend without go in safari ?? i am right ??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52280/discussion-between-omarj-and-darshan-kunjadiya)